# Estimation Question

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: A \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on an open set $A$ containing the closed half plane $H=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Im(z) \ge0 \}$ and that there is a finite constant $M$ with $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z$ in $H$. Sketch any curves and discuss estimates needed to justify your method. Show that $$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+1}=\pi f(i)$$

My approach: $|f(z)| \le M$ implies that $f(z)$ is constant by Lioville's theorem. Therefore, when we need to discuss estimates, I'm integrating in the upper half region of the semi-circle. I'm choosing 2 paths. One of which tends to zero. $$ \left\| \int_{I} \frac{f(x)}{x^2+1}\right\| \le \frac{f(R)}{R^2+1}*\pi R \to0 $$ as $R \to \infty$. Is this the proper way to estimate? $$ \int_{C} \frac{f(x)}{x^2+1}=I+II=II=  \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2+1}=2 \pi i*Res(f,i)$$

Comment: What are you trying to show? Liouville's theorem only applies if your function is analytic on the entire complex plane.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate but in order to do so, we have to estimate. I believe I'm misapplying Lioville's theorem. What does it mean for $|f(z)| \le 1$

Comment: $|f(z)|\leq M$ does not show your function is constant if you only know it is analytic on a neighborhood of the upper half plane.  In fact, there are functions which are analytic and bounded on the upper half plane, but growing exponentially on the lower half plane.  An example that comes to mind is $f(z) = e^{iz}$.  Then $|f(z)| < e^{T}$ if $\text{Im}(z) > -T$, but it is not constant, or even bounded on the imaginary axis.

Comment: @Mehta i meant $|f(z)| \le M$